# .htaccess - Add Trailing Slash And Internal Redirect

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my .htaccess file, I'm using the code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^learn/(.*?)/(.*?)/ /learn.php?lang=$1&topic=$2
RewriteRule ^videos/(.*?)/(.*?)/ /video.php?lang=$1&topic=$2
```

which works fine. But it works on `http://domain.com/learn/v1` and `http://domain.com/learn/v1/` (notice the slash change).
I want to redirect the non-slash version to slash version maintaining the internal redirect above. I tried to add anothe RewriteRule to do that but then it gives me 404.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

# internal rewrites
RewriteRule ^learn/(.*)/(.*)/$ learn.php?lang=$1&topic=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^videos/(.*)/(.*)/$ video.php?lang=$1&topic=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Can you explain what `RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]` this is doing? I'm not very clear about it.

Comment: I wrote a brief comment above that rule. It adds a trailing slash to a URL that is not a file.

Comment: I need to know what that regex selects and works on because this is not my full htaccess file.

Comment: `[^/]$` is pretty simple regex that matches anything that doesn't end with `/`

Comment: You better place your entire .htaccess in question

Comment: I tried your code. Works like a charm. But now it infinitely redirects any 404 page to 404 page again and again. I've removed all other code from htaccess for now. Only this code is present which you've pasted above. It's redirecting with a 302 Status.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95280/discussion-between-mehul-mohan-and-anubhava).